# CSS select next element which has a class

Tags: jquery, css, selector

Is that possible in css or do I need to use jQuery?

My code looks like this:

```
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr class="some-class">...</tr> // I want to select only this one
<tr class="some-class">...</tr>
<tr class="some-class">...</tr>
```

I tried `tr + tr.some-class` but that selects all tr with that class not only the first one.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Can you give an example of the result you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're after the first `<tr>` with class *"some-class"* in a set of `<tr>` elements that follows a sibling without said class, try this

```
tr:not(.some-class) + tr.some-class
```

JSFiddle demo ~ http://jsfiddle.net/gk5wcc55/

Comment: Awesome works perfectly never thought of that thank you :)